# ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" of relation "column_name" violates not-null constraint sequelize postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to manually add data to table with a query and i am getting the error ERROR: null value in column "createdAt" of relation "tenants" violates not-null constraint.

I tried adding and removing the timestamp option and playing around with the attributes of the createdAt column

This is my migrations file

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.createTable('tenants', {
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            company_name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            first_name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            last_name: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            address_1: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            address_2: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: true
            },
            city: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            state: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: true
            },
            postal_code: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            country: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            email: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            phone: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            security_code: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false
            },
            account_status: {
                type: Sequelize.ENUM([
                    'active',
                    'inactive',
                    'deleted'
                ]),
                defaultValue: 'inactive'
            },
            forgotPasswordToken: Sequelize.STRING,
            forgotPasswordTokenSetTime: Sequelize.DATE,
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE,
                defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('NOW()'),
            }
        });
    },

    down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('tenants');
    }
};
```

and this is my models file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Tenants = sequelize.define('tenants', {
        company_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        first_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        last_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        address_1: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        address_2: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        city: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        state: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        postal_code: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        country: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        phone: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        security_code: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM([
                'active',
                'inactive',
                'deleted'
            ]),
            defaultValue: 'inactive'
        },
        forgotPasswordToken: DataTypes.STRING,
        forgotPasswordTokenSetTime: DataTypes.DATE,

    },
        {
            timestamps: true // Enable timestamps
        }

    );
    return Tenants;
}
```

this is my insert query:

```
insert into tenants (company_name, first_name, last_name, address_1, city, postal_code, country, email, phone, security_code, status)

values('Matrix Tech', 'Joe', 'Smith', 'A1 Road', 'New York', '467250', 'USA', 'user1@gmail.com', '123456789', '1234', 'active')
```

Comment: Can you post the `INSERT` statement you are running?

Comment: edited the original post to include the insert statement

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with sequelize but I suspect the actual table does not have the default value set for the column `createdAt` despite it being set in the model file. Can you post the `CREATE` statement for the table?

Comment: sequellize engine creates the tables automaticaly when you make a migrations file. If you look to my above post to the migrations file, that is technically the create statement itself

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize does not support `DEFAULT` values for PostgreSQL, see [the `addColumn()` documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js%7Equeryinterface#instance-method-addColumn). Therefore your table is not created with `DEFAULT` values and when inserting data without explicit values for those columns they default to `NULL` which is not allowed in your case.

The following query should work:

```
insert into tenants (company_name, first_name, last_name, address_1, city, postal_code, country, email, phone, security_code, status, "createdAt", "updatedAt")

values('Matrix Tech', 'Joe', 'Smith', 'A1 Road', 'New York', '467250', 'USA', 'user1@gmail.com', '123456789', '1234', 'active', NOW(), NOW())
```

Comment: i deleted the default values line and im still getting the same error

Comment: You need to pass values in your `INSERT` statement for the columns `createdAt` and `updatedAt` because in Postgres there are no default values for these columns even if you set the default in sequelize.